# MySQL counting nulls with inner join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out the percentage of records which have a null value for a certain field. In this case i have 2 tables; 'Requirements' and 'Deliverables', both tables have an column 'Completion_Date'. I want to count how many Requirements have a null value for 'Completion_Date' plus how many Deliverables have a null value for 'Completion_Date'. I have done inner join and left join to get the total amount of Requirements and Deliverables but my count isn't displaying the correct number of null fields.

My current query:

```
SELECT count(*) as countAll, count(del.Completion_Date) as countNotNull , count(*) - count(del.Completion_Date)  as countNull,
100.0 * count(del.Completion_Date) / count(*) as PercentNotNull, 100.0 * (count(*) - count(del.Completion_Date)) / count(*) as PercentNull
FROM requirements req
INNER JOIN projects pro 
    ON req.Project_ID = pro.Project_ID
INNER JOIN assigned_users u
    ON u.Project_ID=pro.Project_ID
LEFT JOIN deliverables del
    ON del.Project_ID=u.Project_ID
WHERE u.User_ID=4
```

It is currently returning 10 as the total (Correct), 6 not nulls(Should be 8) and 4 nulls (should be 2).

Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: Try to do a `SELECT del.Completion_Date FROM requirements req inner join ... ` to see which rows/values get counted.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your tables data, but I think a problem could be the fact that multiple users can be assigned to the same project, hence the total number of deliverables can be multiplied.

I would try with something like this

```
SELECT  count(*) as countAll,
        count(distinct case when del.Completion_Date is not null then del.deliverableID end) as countNotNull,
        count(distinct case when del.Completion_Date is null then del.deliverableID end) as countNull,
        100.0 * count(distinct case when del.Completion_Date is not null then del.deliverableID end) / count(*) as PercentNotNull,
        100.0 * count(distinct case when del.Completion_Date is null then del.deliverableID end) / count(*) as PercentNull
FROM    projects pro
JOIN    requirements req 
ON      req.Project_ID = pro.Project_ID
JOIN    assigned_users u
ON      u.Project_ID=pro.Project_ID
LEFT JOIN
        deliverables del
ON      del.Project_ID=u.Project_ID
WHERE   u.User_ID = 4
```

Note that in this query I assume the existence of a `deliverableID` column in the `deliverables` table. You will probably have to replace that with the right column.